# only open one JInternalFrame in one time

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I've created a Swing application with several JInternalFrames which gets added to a JDesktopPane on the event of a mouse click. I want only one instance of the same Internal frame to be present on the DesktopPane. I dont want the same frame to appear twice when the user opens the frame..

Comment: Show us anything that you have tried.

Comment: I used this method "removeAll()"

Comment: The idea is : if you are clicking on a Label  or a Button use setEnable(false) this will disable the button until user closes the InternalFrame then Enable the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution to your problem is to create an `HashMap<String,JInternalFrame>`. The `key` will be the title of that `JInternalFrame` and `value` will be the `object` of that `JInternalframe` opened currently.Save the (`key,value`) pair in `HashMap` when the internal frame is opened first time. Disable the close button for all `JInternalFrame` window , so that user can't dispose the displayed `JInternalFrame` window. Register `esc` key to each `JInternalFrame` object , so that when `esc` button of keyboard is pressed the currently display `JInternalFrame` is minimized on the `DesktopPane`.Now When you click on `menu item` to open that same internal frame, check if the `title` of that `JInternalFrame` is existing in that `HashMap` as`key`. If it exists then retrieve the `value` for that `key` and refer it by `JInternalFrame` variable and then restore the same on `DesktopPane`. If the corresponding entry of `title` doesn't exist in that `HashMap` , create a new `JInternalFrame` object, make an entry for same in the `HasMap` and display it.

> ***Note:** Whatever I have posted here is the solution for the situation where
>   you can have many types of `JInternalFrame` each having unique
>   different `functionality`, and you want to keep only one `instance` of
>   each of those `JInternalFrame`.*

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/internalframelistener.html is this useful..

Comment: @luzifer:  yeah.I had went through earlier..you can either hide or minimize the `JInternalFrame` depending upon your need.. What I have posted here is the solution for the situation where you can have many types of `JInternalFrame` each having unique different functionality, and you want to keep only one instance of each of those `JInternalFrame`..

Answer (score 2):

Here is may sample code. hope this help.
Menu action to call internal frame in main application where JdesktopPane in it.

```
 private void YourJinternalFrameMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 

    YourJinternalFrame nw = YourJinternalFrame.getInstance();
    nw.pack();
    //usefull part for you.. if open shows, if not creates new one 
    if (nw.isVisible()) {
    } else {
        desktopPane.add(nw);
        nw.setVisible(true);
    }
    try {

        nw.setMaximum(true);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainApplication.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

put this inside of your YourJinternalFrame

```
private static YourJinternalFrame myInstance;

public static YourJinternalFrame getInstance() {
    if (myInstance == null) {
    myInstance = new YourJinternalFrame();
    }
return myInstance;
```

Comment: This works. However, once you close the JInternalFrame, say with some data entered and open it once more, it opens with the data i.e. it's like the instance of the frame is not destroyed when the frame is closed. How do you deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple code :

```
YourJinternalFrame nw = new YourJinternalFrame();

private void YourJinternalFrameMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    if(!nw.isVisible()){
        YourJDesktopPane.add(nw);
        nw.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (checking for the class name):

```
final JInternalFrame[] frames = desktopPane.getAllFrames();
LoginFrame loginFrame = new LoginFrame();

if( !Arrays.asList(frames).toString().contains("LoginFrame") ) {
    desktopPane.add(loginFrame);
    loginFrame.setVisible(true);
    loginFrame.validate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code 
take class variable chk and set equal to 0
then call jframe method
componentremoved
in this set chk =0 again
and if you call your internal frame set 
chk =1
and compare chk on calling internal wheather it is zero or not 
thats all

Answer (score 0):

I went for a different solution:

```
final JInternalFrame[] frames = desktopPane.getAllFrames();

if( !Arrays.asList(frames).contains(loginFrame) ) {
    loginFrame = new LoginFrame();
    desktopPane.add(loginFrame);
    loginFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```